# C# WinForms - filtering one combobox based on the value of another combobox in a databound datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, filter

I have 4 tables - Agents, Customers, Counties and Towns. Agents and Customers both have a Town field and a County field. I have a DataGridView for each table. These are working great. I have the Town and County as comboboxes using the Towns and Counties table as the datasource.

The problem is that it does not filter the Town based on the selected County. I would like it to do this, but there is no option to filter a combobox field based on the value of another field.

I have searched this up for a while but cant find anything useful.

Can anyone talk me through how to do this, please?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Richard

PS I am using Visual Studio 2010 and mostly design view.

Comment: Are you using a DataSource object like SqlDataSource or ObjectDataSource to get the Counties? if you do then you should pass a select parameter to filter the Counties depending on the value selected in the Town DropDown.

Comment: I am using a DataSet and an mdf file. I dragged the tables onto the DataSet, and then I am using the tables displayed there to visualise the data in the DataGridViews. Sorry if my wording is not correct - I only started on C# 2 days ago.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy, provide related code.

Comment: I dont think there is any need. I am almost there, I think. Refer to stakx' answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can **use `DataView`** as a data source for your comboboxes, since this allows you to filter rows based on a criterion (via the **`RowFilter`** property). I'll show a simple example involving two comboboxes used for selecting a country and a town in that country.

---

First, set up some data to be used:

```
// set up DataTable with countries:
countriesTable = new DataTable("Countries");
countriesTable.Columns.Add("CountryID", typeof(int));
countriesTable.Columns.Add("CountryName", typeof(string));
countriesTable.Rows.Add(1, "England");
countriesTable.Rows.Add(2, "Spain");
...

// set up DataTable with towns:
townsTable = new DataTable("Towns");
townsTable.Columns.Add("TownID", typeof(int));
townsTable.Columns.Add("TownName", typeof(string));
townsTable.Columns.Add("CountryID", typeof(int));   // <-- this is a foreign key
townsTable.Rows.Add(1, "London", 1);
townsTable.Rows.Add(2, "Brighton", 1);
townsTable.Rows.Add(3, "Barcelona", 2);
...
```

---

Next, data-bind the comboboxes to the data:

```
// bind countries to country combobox:
countryComboBox.DataSource = null;
countryComboBox.DisplayMember = "CountryName";
countryComboBox.ValueMember = "CountryID";
countryComboBox.DataSource = countriesTable;

// bind towns to town combobox:    
townsView = new DataView(townsTable, "CountryID = 1", ...);  // use foreign key
townComboBox.DataSource = null;                              // in a row filter
townComboBox.DisplayMember = "TownName";
townComboBox.ValueMember = "TownID";
townComboBox.DataSource = townsView;
```

---

Finally, whenever another country is selected in the country combobox, update the row filter:

```
private void countryComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    townsView.RowFilter = string.Format("CountryID = {0}",
                                            countryComboBox.SelectedValue);
}
```

I believe you could automate this last step using databinding and a custom `Format` event handler, but I won't go into details.

Comment: This looks to be the right answer (or **a** right answer in any case). I am working on it, and will mark as answer if I resolve it this way.

Comment: I was receiving a `System.NullReferenceException` at event SelectedIndexSelected. Currently, I don't know why, but after swapping the order of lines `countryComboBox.DataSource = countriesTable;` with `countryComboBox.ValueMember = "CountryID";` it worked fine.

Comment: @DanielBonetti: Thanks for the hint. I've fixed my code. The additional initial `DataSource = null` is to ensure that the new `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` won't get applied to some previously set data source. `DataSource` should always be set *after* `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`, due to performance considerations.

Comment: @stakx, did it work for you? In this case, instead of showing the country names in the `countryComboBox` it's showing `System.Data.DataRowView`.

Comment: @DanielBonetti: Yes, the above code works for me. One instance where you will end up with *System.Data.RowView* displayed in the combo box is when `countryComboBox.DisplayMember` contains a typo or a column name that doesn't actually exist in the data source.

Answer (score 1):

How is your data bound? If you use a DataView you can specify the [RowFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx) property and then refresh the underlying data. The rowfilter property works like a where clause and only returns a subset of the actual data.

[A little background on DataView](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/02/11/2798.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To be able to do this you should have a Country foreign key field in you Towns table.

If you have it, the problem is probably in how your Towns combobox is databound, i.e. choosing Datasource property. You should't bind it directly to a Towns table but to a Towns "foreign key" of a Country table. You can do this in design view I think.

Comment: Think this is probably it. It was originally text just whilst I got started on it, but since then I have made a lot of progress and am now adding more things like Town / County lookup instead of having, for example, Blandford for one customer but Blandford Forum for another. This way it will one name for each town, so search results will be more accurate.

Answer (score -1):

This is my new answer.  It turns out I read the question wrong (sorry about that).  In my example I am using an OleDb connection to an Access Database.  This is a code snippet from an app that I am currently using (names of comboboxes and tables have been changed for the example).  All it does is query the database whenever the selection is changed on comboBox1 and add the result to comboBox2.

```
            private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Open connection to database...
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query1 = "select * from Your_Table where Title='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
            command.CommandText = query1;

            OleDbDataReader reader1 = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader1.Read())
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(reader1["ColumnName"].ToString());
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }
    }
```

This will query your database based on comboBox1 and put the results in comboBox2 based on your selection.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The question was asked for filtering combobox, not for datagridview. BindingSource can not filter ComboBox.

Comment: I did read the question wrong.  Wish I would have caught that before you gave me negative rep... thanks for that!